# catkin_make: command not found

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a newbie. I get this when trying to use the commad catkin_make please help

catkin_make: command not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212492/catkin_make:-command-not-found/) by [jorge.vargas](https://answers.ros.org/users/22977/jorge.vargas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you've indeed already installed ROS, don't forget to source your /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash (and add it to your ~/.bashrc!)

To execute the command:

```
> source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

To add to your ~/.bashrc:

```
> echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to source the `setup.bash` file that goes with it. For example, if you're using ROS Jade on Ubuntu and installed from apt-get, you'd need to first do:

```
$ source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash
```

After sourcing the correct setup file, you'll have `catkin_make` on your path.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4